# Align text vertically and horizontally in CSS button

Tags: html, css

I have a  that has been styled in CSS to look like a button. The problem I'm having though is that the button MUST be 185px wide and 75px high. Which I get right, but the text of the button is floating somewhere on top to the left.

How do I get the text to display exactly in the middle of the button? I've created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGDUw/) so you guys can check it out.

```
//Ignore this comment.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change height to `line-height` and add `text-align:center`

```
.button-large{
    text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
  width: 185px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(116, 79, 145);
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(156, 125, 185);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(156, 125, 185) 30%, rgb(170, 150, 201) 70%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(156, 125, 185) 30%, rgb(170, 150, 201) 70%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(156, 125, 185) 30%, rgb(170, 150, 201) 70%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(156, 125, 185) 30%, rgb(170, 150, 201) 70%);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(156, 125, 185) 30%, rgb(170, 150, 201) 70%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow:         0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cGDUw/2/)**

Comment: Huh? I'm going to have to wait 12mins to accept. Some restriction on StackOverflow

Comment: Ahh! Sorry English is not my first language haha.